# Telerik RadDatePicker Control

Tags: c#, telerik

I am using Telerik's RadDatePicker control which i think is essentially a DateTime control and i would like to extract the selected date and string it to a variable. Would be great if someone could help me on this.

Comment: u want to make datetime as string?

Comment: yup, to insert into my db or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C#:

```
DateTime? selectedDate = RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate;
//to string
string date="";
if(selectedDate!=null)
{
   date=selectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString();//or selectedDate.Value.ToString("d");
}
else
{
   //handle the case when user has not selected any date, and selectedDate is null
}
```

You can format the string representation following [article in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Comment: This works, however it seems to include the time as well. How can i remove it?

Comment: use [selectedDate.ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

Comment: Receiving an error: does not contain a defintion for .ToShortDateString

Comment: which version of .net you are using? use: selectedDate.ToString("d")

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguement

Comment: oops, i did a basic mistake. It should be selectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString() or  selectedDate.Value.ToString("d"), i have modified the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
string myDate = RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate.HasValue ?
                RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString() :
                string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime dt =Convert.ToDateTime( RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate);
          string  temp = dt.ToShortDateString();

Found the answer at [Telerik DatePicker Control](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-get-only-date-part-from-of-selected-date-in-raddatepicker)

Answer (score -1):

```
String.Format("{0:d}", RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate.ToString()); prints just date alone
```

Comment: This seems to print the time still

Comment: If you call `ToString()` on the data first, the `d` format won't have any effect, because there is no way to format a string.